# Variadic template max function trouble

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a variadic template for finding the maximum of an arbitrary amount of numbers (this is just for practicing variadic templates).

However, I have sort of hit a wall and can't understand why my current attempt simply does not work, and fails at compile time with the error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'A myMax(A, A, Args ...) [with A = int, Args = {}]':
prog.cpp:7:35:   instantiated from 'A myMax(A, A, Args ...) [with A = int, Args = {int}]'
prog.cpp:22:26:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:7:35: error: no matching function for call to 'myMax(int)'
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename A, typename ... Args>
A myMax(A a, A b, Args ... args)
{
   return myMax(myMax(a,b),args...);
}

template <typename A>
A myMax(A a,A b)
{
   if (a>b)
      return a;
   else
      return b;
}


int main()
{
   std::cout<<myMax(1,5,2);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix my variadic template?

Comment: OK, but once you're done learning, please go back and use `std::max` :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just define the overload which takes two arguments above the  variadic function template:

```
template <typename A> 
A myMax(A a,A b)      //this is an overload, not specialization
{
   if (a>b)
      return a;
   else
      return b;
}

template <typename A, typename ... Args>
A myMax(A a, A b, Args ... args)
{
   return myMax(myMax(a,b),args...);
}
```

Now it will work: http://www.ideone.com/R9m61

The overload should be visible at the point of instantiation, which is in the variadic function template.

Comment: Woah, this was a surprising answer to me.  So simple!  I was expecting something more complex about partial specialization vs overloading.  Will it also work to add a function signature just after `#include <iostream>`?  Ex: `template <typename A> A myMax(A a, A b);`

Answer (score 4):

A shorter variaton of the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42811014/3850022) using `std::max`, try it [here](https://ideone.com/WbEsMO):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> 
T Max(T a) 
{
    return a;
}

template <typename T, typename ... Args> 
T Max(T a, Args ... args) 
{
    return std::max(Max(args...), a);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Max(14,45,87,66,99,888,554,21);
}
```

Comment: Don't say "above", since you can't be sure what order answers will be in, or which answers will remain undeleted. Instead, link to the answer via the share link below it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `constexpr`, it is now possible to do something like the following:

```
template<typename num_t, num_t ...X>
constexpr num_t max_element(){
    const std::array<num_t, sizeof...(X)> vals{X...};
    num_t ret = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof...(X); i++)
        if(vals[i] > ret)
            ret = vals[i];
    return ret;
}
```

I tried going one step further, using simply:

```
const std::array<num_t, sizeof...(X)> vals{X...};
return *std::max_element(vals.cbegin(), vals.cend());
```

but the compiler complained (I forget exactly what it said. [**Edit:** see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32695935/2399799) which explains the situation for std::alogrithm more generally.]

Anyway, you use it simply as:

```
auto max_val =  max_element<int, 11, 88, 12, 2>();
assert(max_val == 88);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
T Max(T a, T b)
{
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}

template<class T, class... a>
T Max(T x , a... z)
{
    T k = Max(z...);
    return (x > k ? x : k);
}

int main()
{
    cout << Max(14,45,87,66,99,888,554,21);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without extra binary overload:

```
template <typename... Ts>
auto Max(Ts... ts)
{
    auto a = (ts,...);
    auto max = [&](const auto& b)
    {
        return a = std::max(a, b);         
    };
    return ((max(ts)), ...);
}
int main() {
    std::cout << Max(11,4,87,2,99);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is some overhead in my case unluckily, compiling with cl.exe -O2 for x32. In assembly code, it actually compares the last argument with itself.