# Why aren't std::algorithms constexpr and which could be?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14, constexpr

Why aren't any `std::algorithm` methods `constexpr`? If I understand the new C++14 rules correctly, many of these methods could be `constexpr`. For example, why can't `std::find` be `constexpr`?

```
static constexpr std::array<char, 4> DnaBases {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};

constexpr bool is_dna(char b)
{
    return std::find(std::cbegin(DnaBases), std::cend(DnaBases), b) != std::cend(DnaBases); // why not?
}
```

Which other `std::algorithm`s could be `constexpr`?

Comment: The bottom line is you can not evaluate a function at compile time when you have no idea what data it is going to process. That has to happen at runtime.

Comment: @Galik: Not true; the language allows a `constexpr` method to be used with non-`constexpr` data.

Comment: But it will only evaluate at compile time if the data passed to it is constexpr. Otherwise it will be compiled as a normal function.

Comment: @Galik: yes, that's the point; if you loose nothing from declaring as `constexpr`, then you can only win.

Comment: [Related Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18052208/819272) wrt containers and utilities.

Answer (score 13):

It could be `constexpr`, but cannot be evaluated as a constant expression, since in this case, for example for compile-time find it is required that: 
`begin/end` should be constexpr, the `* operator` of the iterator should be constexpr, `operator ==` should be constexpr, `operator !=` for the iterator should be constexpr, `operator ++` for the iterator should be constexpr. But, if all functions are `constexpr`, then many algorithms can be implemented with `constexpr`.

You can look at the [SPROUT library](https://github.com/bolero-MURAKAMI/Sprout/tree/master/sprout) for the implementation of constexpr containers/algorithms.

And related talk on the [isocpp.org forums](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/wdh1lLlRnX4)

Comment: Is there any reason why these operators couldn't in theory be `constexpr` (assuming underlying type can be made `constexpr`)?

Comment: Since `std::find` is a function *template*, it can be marked what has formerly been "conditional constexpr". Function templates do not have to produce functions which are valid constexpr functions for every set of template arguments. However, there should be at least one set of arguments such that an instantiation is a valid constexpr function (so an unconditional `throw` must not appear, for example).

Comment: Even in a non-template `constexpr` function, there is still a certain conditionality. The result of a call to such a function is not always a constant expression - instead, it is a constant expression *if and only if* all the arguments are constant expressions. I guess my point here is that it the compiler already is forced to do a very context-specific decision (is this constant or not?) at each call. So why not simply ignore `constexpr` and simply encourage the compiler to make everything "as constant as possible"?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I think you'd have to mandate rather than merely encourage, otherwise it'd be up to the quality of the compiler what can be used as an ICE, which wouldn't be much fun. As for why the `constexpr` keyword is needed, as opposed to the language just giving something the semantics of `constexpr` if and only if it would (under the current rules) be valid for `constexpr` to be added to it, I'm not sure. Maybe because if you ODR-use a constexpr object then it needs exactly one definition, so the authors felt it would be useful for this to be explicit in the code?

Answer (score 11):

Functions cannot be overloaded based on `constexpr`-ness. As a result, any function defined as `constexpr` needs to be implemented in a form which could be a `constexpr`. This requirement imposes constraints on all implementations.

The C++14 specification is somewhat relaxed with respect to the constraints compared to C++11. However, when the specification was finalized nobody was confident that all optimizations which can be achieved without the `constexpr` constraint can be achieved when algorithms are mandated to be `constexpr`. Without knowing that the non-`constexpr` functionality is not impeded by mandating `constexpr` implementations the algorithms won't be defined to be `constexpr`. The non-`constexpr` use of algorithms is still assumed to be the primary use of algorithms.

It may be worth having a special set of algorithms which are defined to be `constexpr`. I'm not aware of a correspnding proposal. I also don't see a lot if demand warranting standardization but my perception may be different from other's.

Comment: I agree any function that would require modification to be `constexpr` should not be. But it seems some could be declared `constexpr` without modification (including `std::find`). The restriction is then only on the parameter types satisfying `constexpr`-ness (which is a separate issue).

Comment: @Daniel: Maybe you have only seen trivial implementations of `std::find()`? Even for something like `std::find()` I can imagine improvements over a naïve implementation, notably dealing with segments, which would be made harder, at least, having to formulate them as `constexpr` (admittedly, I'd be more happy if implementations would implement the segmented optimization).

Comment: I don't see what improvements could be made over the naive algorithm (which is the algorithm used in libc++). Unless you are referring to a multi-threaded solution.

Comment: @Daniel: the immediately obvious improvements for `std::find()` are loop-unrolling (which the compiler does for some data structures but not for others), vectorization (again something the compiler may or may not do), and as already mentioned above dealing specifically with segmented sequences like `std::deque<T>` or `std::istreambuf_iterator<cT>`. I haven't verified it but I can imagine that the formulation needed for `constexpr` puts off the optimizer in some form, i.e., resulting in less optimized code.

Comment: @Daniel `std::find` might, for instance, dispatch to `memchr` (which is highly optimized), given appropriate arguments. MSVC's `find` does that.

Answer (score 6):

The current (C++14) Standard Library is [**pretty much under-powered**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052208/which-parts-of-the-c14-standard-library-could-be-and-which-parts-will-be-made) w.r.t. to the corresponding Core Language capabilities concerning `constexpr`.

E.g., MSVC 2015, which only has C++11 language support for `constexpr`, [**could almost fully implement**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/02/constexpr-complete-for-vs-2015-rtm-c-11-compiler-c-17-stl.aspx) the entire C++14 Standard Library usage of `constexpr`. The only exceptions were `std::min`, `std::max`, `std::minmax`, `std::min_element`, `std::max_element`, `std::minmax_element` for `std::initializer_list`.

As of C++1z (17?), the `std::xxx_element` algorithms will become `constexpr` algorithms for general iterator and comparator inputs to unify the usage for `std::initializer_list`. Furthermore, there are [**proposals for `constexpr` lambda**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf) functions for C++1z as well.

With lambdas being upgraded, there are still a few core language limitations left to prevent the entire `<algorithm>` header from becoming `constexpr`. (Note that these are not hard-core technological obstacles, [**most of them could be resolved**](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/std-proposals/constexpr$20dynamic/std-proposals/qcKUf-U7_YU/SRfxv76_ekkJ) by allowing the compiler to evaluate them).

1. Some algorithms can dynamically allocate memory by calling `std::get_temporary_buffer` (`std::inplace_merge`, `std::stable_sort` and `std::stable_partition`) which is not allowed in `constexpr` contexts.
2. Some algorithms can fall back to low-level C routines such as `memset` (`std::fill` and `std::fill_n`) that would prevent library authors from using these algorithms in `constexpr` contexts.
3. Some algorithm implementations can benefit from the judicious use of `goto` (e.g. `std::nth_element`, `std::stable_sort`), for which a [**`C++1z` proposal**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4472.html) was rejected.
4. Last but not least, `constexpr` is an interface change, promising that all future implementations will have to deliver this promise. For that reason, implementations are not allowed to add `constexpr` as a Quality of Implementation feature (in contrast to `noexcept`).

Especially the 4th issue stalls the experimentation with how much `constexpr` could be pushed for the Standard Library (algorithms, containers and other utilities). Instead, a separate proposal has to be written and approved for every expansion of `constexpr`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the subject of Antony Polukhin's  proposal P0202:

[**Add Constexpr Modifiers to Functions in  and  Headers**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0202r1.html)

which I hope would be adopted by the C++ [Library Evolution Working Group](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee) and make its way into C++20.

Answer (score 0):

`std::algorithm` algorithms act on iterators. There is a technical reason why making them `constexpr` would usually either prevent compiling them (in C++11) or do nothing (in C++14 or with conditional-`constexpr`), but there's also a semantic reason why it wouldn't make sense for them to be `constexpr`.

**The technical reason** is that `constexpr` functions cannot call non-`constexpr` expressions. ForEveR points out that template `constexpr` functions can't be evaluated at compile-time if they call non-`constexpr` expressions.

In the case of `std::algorithm`, evaluating `constexpr` functions in `std::algorithm` would require the functions for accessing container iterators to be `constexpr`, which in turn would require the iterators themselves to be `constexpr` types. But this is impossible almost by definition; containers are typically designed as lightweight access to heap-allocated memory, but heap memory cannot be allocated at compile time (of course). In the comments below, dyp points out that iterators don't always point to containers, but even these iterators are unlikely to be useable at compile-time; for instance, streams objects are of course not readable or writeable at compile time, since IO cannot be done at compile time.

**This leads to the semantic problem:** `constexpr` semantically means that a function is intended to be possible to evaluate at compile time. Declaring functions conditionally-`constexpr` when it is *impossible* to evaluate them at compile time would make the API confusing and misleading.

Now, **I think the language would be improved if there were a way to create and use containers at compile time;** this would make `constexpr` that much more similar to Lisp's macro capabilities. This may eventually be added, but currently it's not really supported by existing standard library code. The most flexible approach, of allowing some objects to live on the heap *during compile time*, is, as mentioned above, not supported at all by the core language, and it would create some serious complications. For instance, what would it be legal to *do* with such objects? Either their lifetimes would need to be limited to compile-time only, or they would need to be included as static const memory in the final program (like a string literal), or...what?

Comment: The `<algorithm>` algorithms act on *iterators*, or *iterator-ranges*, not Containers. Additionally, function *templates* marked as `constexpr` may produce instantiations that are no valid `constexpr` functions (formerly, they were *conditionally `constexpr`*).

Comment: @dyp What exactly is an iterator or iterator-range without a corresponding container?

Comment: Ranges generating values, for example boost's `counting_range`; other iterators such as `istream_iterator` refer to a stream, not a Container. There are filter ranges which refer to other ranges etc.

Comment: @dyp Streams, of course, also can't exist at compile time, but point taken.

Comment: [Here's an example of the "conditional `constexpr`"](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Zhwl6HBchLc5udg9): While `foo(4.2)` is a constant expression, `foo(42)` is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

Add the latest status for [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) for reference, since GCC 10.1, we finally have the full support for `constexpr` algorithm!

> Add constexpr modifiers to functions in  and 
> Headers   [P0202R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0202r3.html)    10.1    __cpp_lib_constexpr_algorithms >= 201703L