# Constexpr find for array using c++17

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, constexpr

I am trying to write a constexpr find function that will return the index of a std::array containing a certain value. The function below seems to work OK except when the contained type is `const char*`:

```
#include <array>

constexpr auto name1() {
    return "name1";
}

constexpr auto name2() {
    return "name2";
}

template <class X, class V>
constexpr auto find(X& x, V key) {
    std::size_t i = 0;
    while(i < x.size()) {
        if(x[i] == key) return i;
        ++i;
    }

    return i;
}


int main() {

    constexpr std::array<const char*, 2> x{{name1(), name2()}};
    constexpr auto f1 = find(x, name1()); // this compiles
    constexpr auto f2 = find(x, name2()); // this doesn't...
}
```

The weird thing is that `find(x, name1())` compiles cleanly but `find(x, name2())` fails with the error:

```
subexpression not valid in a constant expression
        if(x[i] == key) return i; `
```

How can this expression work when used with `name1()` but fail when used with `name2()`?

I have also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397794/constexpr-find-implementation), but the user builds the array class from scratch and I do not want to do that.

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that when comparing a `const char*`, you compare pointers, which can't be done at compile time. However this doesn't explain why the first `find()` call doesn't compile.

Comment: @MivVG The duplicate mentioned in the post explains this.

Comment: Yeah I saw it after posting this comment

Comment: so, to confirm, what I am trying to do cannot work with const char* because I am not allowed to compare pointers at compile time?

Comment: from what I've noticed, even this simple snippet `constexpr auto x = (name1() == name2());` fails to compile, while this `constexpr auto x = (name1() == name1());` does...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a compiler bug. Both `f1` and `f2` should fail to compile in the same way.

The main issue is that it's an *assumption* that `"name1" == "name1"` and `"name1" != "name2"`. The standard in fact provides no such guarantees, see [[lex.string]/16](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#16):

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a [*string-literal*](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#16) yield the same or a different object is unspecified.

Even though the assumption most likely holds, comparing unspecified values inside `constexpr` is expressly not allowed, see [[expr.const]/2.23](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.23):

> — a relational ([[expr.rel]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel)) or equality ([[expr.eq]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq)) operator where the result is unspecified;

A workaround (and the right thing to do) would be to not rely on addresses of string literals and instead compare the actual strings. For example:

```
constexpr bool equals(const char* a, const char* b) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; ; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) return false;
        if (a[i] == 0) break;
    }
    return true;
}

template <class X, class V>
constexpr auto find(X& x, V key) {
    std::size_t i = 0;
    while(i < x.size()) {
        if(equals(x[i], key)) return i;
        ++i;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Another alternative is to use `std::string_view` in place of `const char*`.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Thank you. I haven't reported it yet; I will do so later and post a link here.

Comment: `std::string_view` has a really bad support in MSVC in debug version of stl, even in the latest msvc2022. So be careful with it.