# GCC hand made constexpr find vs std::find

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, constexpr

I'm trying to implement a constexpr find with c++17 to find the index of a matching element in an array ([from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)) very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114180/constexpr-find-for-array-using-c17). Below is a very simple implementation with an `int` array.

```
namespace mine{
    template<typename InputIter, typename T>
    constexpr inline InputIter find(InputIter first, InputIter last, const T& val)
    {
        for(; first!=last; ++first)
            if(*first == val) return first;

        return first;        
    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::array<int, 5> a{4, 10, 5, 889, 45};
    auto b = mine::find(a.begin(), a.end(), 5);
    auto c = std::distance(a.begin(), b);

    return c;
}
```

The problem is GCC trunk is unable to deduce `mine::find` at compile time!! ([live code `mine::find`](https://godbolt.org/z/1HBgJp)).
However, simply by changing the switch to `-std=c++2a` (as c++20 marks `std::find` as `constexpr`), `std::find` gives me the expected results ([live code `std::find`](https://godbolt.org/z/k7_e-C)).

**Edit:** How can I get the same results as `std::find` with `mine::find` for the same optimization level without changing code in `main()`? (`mind::find` can of course be changed keeping a similar interface)
And what makes GCC optimize `std::find` better for the same optimization level?

**Edit 2:** Declaring `b` here as `constexpr` gives an error ([live code with error](https://godbolt.org/z/hznsY4))

```
int main()
{
    const std::array<int, 5> a{4, 10, 5, 889, 45};
    constexpr auto b = mine::find(a.begin(), a.end(), 5);
    auto c = std::distance(a.begin(), b);

    return c;
}
```

Note: Clang trunk seems to deduce `mine::find` correctly. But this has little to do with `constexpr` IMHO as clang deduces the result even without it.

Comment: If you care about this, why aren't you using `-O3`?

Comment: What do you mean "unable to deduce"? Your link shows it compiling, and your example doesn't require it to be `constexpr`?

Comment: If you want to call your method at compile time, use it in constant expression: add constexpr for `b`. Currently, you just check how good is compiler to optimize the code.

Comment: @Barry I think they are asking about this [error](https://godbolt.org/z/PR5aJk).

Comment: @Bob__ I don't think so. OP provided two code examples, one with `std::find` (optimized away), and second with `mine::find` (non-optimized). They just use the wrong wording.

Comment: @Xenonamous If your question is "why compiler doesn't generate any assembly for `std::find`", then the answer is "because it knows how to optimize standard functions better than non-standard". GCC happens to optimize your `mine::find` as well, when you pass `-O3` flag instead of `-O2`: https://godbolt.org/z/UvGHut

Comment: @Bob__ I don't make assumptions about what people mean. It's up to them to clearly state what the problem is, it's not up to us to guess.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you are right. My intention was to understand what is making `std::find` be better optimized compared to the hand made function. I understand that `-O3` forces the compiler to work harder to optimize the code but what is making GCC optimize away `std::find` compared to `mind::find` for the same optimization level?

Comment: @Barry and @Jarod42, declaring `b` as `constexpr` just gives out an error as @Bob__'s comment shows

Comment: To answer such question would require a person deeply involved in compiler creation, or at least knowledgeable of different options for optimizing (note that `-O3` is pretty much an alias for a lot of separate optimization options). It's pretty much how creators of gcc wanted it to work, so it works this way. My guess is that knowing all the ins and outs of standard library enables compiler to optimize it much better and faster than doing the same for unknown functions from the outside. The increased cost of optimizing user functions lead to decision to put it in the higher optimization level.

Comment: @Xenonamous So please edit your question with the actual code that your question is about. Neither nor question, nor the links, declare `b` constexpr.

Comment: @Xenonamous: with missing `static`, [constexpr version works](https://godbolt.org/z/inWVEw).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you very much `static` was the missing link in my understanding. The nice part is that making this `static` means that the compiler is really able to do compile time evaluation even with `-O0` (boils down to a `MOV` instruction as expected). Can you please submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

constexpr function are not required to be called at compile time unless there are used in const expression. You rely then to compiler optimization.

Turning your (calling) code in constexpr ensures compile time computation:

```
int main()
{
    static constexpr std::array<int, 5> a{4, 10, 5, 889, 45};
    constexpr auto b = mine::find(a.begin(), a.end(), 5);
    constexpr auto c = std::distance(a.begin(), b);

    return c; // return 2 directly
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/inWVEw)